# AngularJS, DropzoneJS, JSON -- refresh file list on success upload

Tags: javascript, php, json, angularjs, dropzone.js

i have "file manager page" with DropzoneJS (for upload) and AngularJS ng-repeat for displaying all saved files (through ng-controller which http.gets json file with the file list).

DropZoneJS strikes event "successfullupload" and i would like to refresh angularly displayed file list.

Is there any way how to achieve this, or is the model totally wrong (as far as i want to call ng-controller function from dropzone event)?

Actual code:

```html
<div class="container">
 <div ng-app="" ng-controller="filesController">
  
  <input ng-model="searchText">
  
  <table class="table table-striped">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>File Name</th>
     <th>File Size</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in files | filter:searchText | orderBy:'name' ">
     <td>{{ x.name }}</td> <td>{{ x.filesize }}</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </div>
</div>
    <script src="js/dropzone.js"></script>
    <script>
     var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#myId", { url: "content/uploadscript.php"});

     myDropzone.on("queuecomplete", function(progress) {
       //location.reload(); //refreshing file list
     }); 

     function filesController($scope,$http) {
         $http.get("content/files.php?list")
         .success(function(response) {$scope.files = angular.fromJson(response);  });
     }
    </script>
```

Thank You in advance

Comment: I don't know dropzonejs but I think you can try the following. Return the just uploaded file from the server side, and in your success function do something like this `.success(function(response){ $scope.list = response['file'] })`

Comment: when i put $scope.files = data...; into success handler, $scope cannot be accessed -- it is not "defined", iam doing something totally wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$scope.$on('successfullupload',function(event,data){
  $scope.list=data;
  //assuming $scope.successfullupload was broadcast, and can pass a json which contains the new list
});
```

I believe reacting on an event is the way to go in your situation.

You need to place the dropzone event listener inside your controller, like so:

```
<script>
    function filesController($scope,$http) {
        $http.get("content/files.php?list")
        .success(function(response) {$scope.files = angular.fromJson(response);  });//get initial $scope.files value

var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#myId", { url: "content/uploadscript.php"});

    myDropzone.on("queuecomplete", function(progress) {//event listener
         $http.get("content/files.php?list")
        .success(function(response) {$scope.files = angular.fromJson(response);  });//will refresh $scope.files
    });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: iam actually a bit lost in scopes, can i even (ive updated code in original post) access filesController from queuecomplete event handler?

Comment: yes you can, if you move your dropzone event listener into your angular controller; I've updated my answer accordingly